# Scraping specific data from edgar

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

there is a piece of HTML code

```
<tr bgcolor="#cceeff" style="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Def.-Times; font-size:8pt">
<td colspan="3" valign="top"> <p style=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; margin-left:2.00em; text-indent:-1.00em; font-size:8pt; font-family:ARIAL"><b>{99}</b> <b></b>Receivables becoming Defaulted Receivables during period</p></td>
<td align="right" valign="bottom"><font style="font-family:ARIAL; ">1,310,326.05</font></td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="bottom"><font style="font-family:ARIAL; "> </font></td>
 <td valign="bottom"> </td>
 <td valign="bottom"></td>
 <td valign="bottom"></td>
```

How Can I extract the data like

```
{4}Defaulted Receivables', '{4}', '1,310,326.05']
```

I had a code that a person gave me

```
def get_row(soup, n):
    return [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in soup.select('tr:contains("{' + str(n) + '}") td') if td.get_text(strip=True)]
```

but the first, I don't understand how to find a 'row' in HTML code.
second,  `tr:contains("{' + str(n) + '}") td` what this code do??
sorry I'm so new to the scraping and HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've improved/corrected code, now it will print list of lists of entries texts for each row.

Code needs beautiful soup and lxml to be installed once: `python -m pip install lxml bs4`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64075251#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install lxml bs4
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<tr bgcolor="#cceeff" style="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Def.-Times; font-size:8pt">
<td colspan="3" valign="top"> <p style=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; margin-left:2.00em; text-indent:-1.00em; font-size:8pt; font-family:ARIAL"><b>{99}</b> <b></b>Receivables becoming Defaulted Receivables during period</p></td>
<td align="right" valign="bottom"><font style="font-family:ARIAL; ">1,310,326.05</font></td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="bottom"><font style="font-family:ARIAL; "> </font></td>
 <td valign="bottom"> </td>
 <td valign="bottom"></td>
 <td valign="bottom"></td>
</tr>
""", 'lxml')

print([[
    td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td') if td.get_text(strip=True)
] for tr in soup.select('tr')])
```

Code prints:

```
[['{99}Receivables becoming Defaulted Receivables during period', '1,310,326.05']]
```